# Postgresql error syntax error at or near "pg_restore"

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I am getting syntax error at or near "pg_restore":

```
pg_restore -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d old_db -v
```

Comment: http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `pg_restore` is a program for the command line. It's not a SQL statement.

Answer (score 3):

From: https://www.reddit.com/r/PostgreSQL/comments/e6ezai/getting_a_syntax_error_when_trying_to_restore/

That means you are running pg_restore from within psql. But pg_restore is a command line program (not a SQL command) just like psql.exe (or createdb.exe or cmd.exe) so you need to run that on the command line, not within psql.